# How to send multiple arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am facing a proble while sending multiple data in javascript..Let me demonstrate my code..

```
<td><input type="button" onclick="deletecom(<?php echo 
 $id,$employee>)"name="delete" value="Delete"></td>
 </tr>
 <script language="javascript">
 function deletecom(delcom,delcom1)
 {
     if(confirm("are u sure"))
     {
         window.location.href='delete_commision.php?del_com='+delcom+ 
'&del_com1='+delcom1+;


        return true;

     }
 }


 </script>
```

Here is my delete_commision.php code

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include("index.php");
include("includes/connect.php");
$del_com=$_GET['del_com'];
$del_com1=$_GET['del_com1'];

echo $del_com,$hello;
echo $del_com1;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I used to click or send the arguments it not showing the values of second variable..

here is the output..

```
Notice: Undefined index: del_com1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Neisha\delete_commision.php on line 7
```

21

Here the 21 is the value that I am passing i.e ID

The 1st variable is showing the correct value but I am not understanding the second one's problem

Comment: what is the url you see in addressbar ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: @Indranil Just remove the `+` sign at the end of `window.location.href`

Comment: Also check the closing syntax of php tag in calling javascript function

Comment: Change the onclick to `onclick="deletecom(<?= $id?>,<?=$employee?>)"` and test it.

Comment: I done all the changes but now only the confirmation @Yash Parekh but now only the confirmation window is appearing and when I used to click in yes then the page is not redirecting to the link page i.e "delete_commision.php"

Comment: @Indranil Check comment on my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Change your onclick value with this
`onclick="deletecom( <?php echo $id ?>, <?php echo $employee ?>)"`

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" onclick="deletecom(<?php echo $id.",".$employee ?>)" name="delete" value="Delete">
    </td>
</tr>
<script language="javascript">
    function deletecom(delcom,delcom1)
    {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete??"))
        {
            window.location.href='delete_commision.php?del_com='+delcom+'&del_com1='+delcom1;
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Neisha\view_commision.php on line 129

Comment: <td><input type="button" onclick="deletecom(<?php echo $id,$employee; ?>)" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>

Comment: Change that line to :-  `<td><input type="button" onclick="deletecom(<?php echo $id.",".$employee; ?>)" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>` I've already mentioned that thing in my answer above...

Comment: I already tried ur suggestion like u said but now its showing the confirmation box and when I used to click on "YES" then the page is not reditecting to the "delete_commision.php" page.

Comment: Check your console for errors and If its all okay then copy the delete link and paste it in browser with values. I think this happens because of path mismatch.

Comment: How to check for errors ..?..Actually I am beginner in php so I dont have idea on that...I checked in google also but I didn't get that..

Comment: For javascript error check your console logs (by pressing F12 key on your browser page) and for php error use `try...catch` block...

Answer (score -2):

Yes oF Course you can pass multiple arguments using java scripts

here go through this example so you can have an idea on it

```
var sum = function () {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        res += parseInt(arguments[i]);
    }
    return res;
 }
```